# How can I print a newline properly in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I was trying to make Tic Tac Toe game for the monthly tutorial and wrote this code to make a box first:

```
box :: [String]
box = ["0 | 1 | 2",
       "---------",
       "3 | 4 | 5",
       "---------",
       "6 | 7 | 8"]
```

I get this output in GHCi:

```
["0 | 1 | 2\n","---------\n","3 | 4 | 5\n","---------\n","6 | 7 | 8\n"]
```

I wanted to get:

```
 0 | 1 | 2
 ---------
 3 | 4 | 5
 ---------
 6 | 7 | 8
```

How can I print the grid like this?

Comment: What function are you using to output it?

Comment: I am not using any function but working at GHCi prompt

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try something like:

```
box = unlines $ ["0 | 1 | 2",
                 "---------",
                 "3 | 4 | 5",
                 "---------",
                 "6 | 7 | 8"]
```

Then output the box using `putStr`:

```
main = putStr box
```

What `unlines` does is take a list of strings and join them together using newlines. It basically treats the list of strings as a list of lines and turns them into a single string.

`putStr` just prints the string to STDOUT. If you used `print` or GHCi to look at the string instead, newlines would be rendered as `\n` rather than actual newlines. This happens because the `show` instance of a `String` is designed to serialize the string as you would have inputted it rather than printing it. Both `print` and GHCi use `show` before outputting to STDOUT.

If you are at the GHCi prompt and want to see what the string actually looks like, you can use `putStr` directly:

```
*Main> putStr box
0 | 1 | 2
---------
3 | 4 | 5
---------
6 | 7 | 8
*Main>
```

Comment: @dave4420: Wow, I was not paying attention! Thanks for fixing my error.

Comment: Don't thank me, thank my insomnia. You can also improve your answer by either being consistent about using `putStr`/`putStrLn`, or by noting the difference between them.

Comment: Ooh, good point. I meant to use `putStr` throughout, but I'm so used to `putStrLn` that it just gets typed by instinct :)

Comment: @ Tikhon 
Can you please tell me if there is any way in which i can give input of Maybe Int and convert it into Int. I was working on the following code.
`code`
    
    `moves = do`
    `putStrLn " Enter the number"`
    `number <- readLn :: IO Int`
    `print number`
    `findposition number box = findIndex (==number) box :: Int`

Comment: @user: You should ask a new question for that.

Comment: @user And when you ask your new question, don't forget to say what you want to happen when the `Maybe Int` is `Nothing`.

Answer (score 8):

Another approach is

```
main = mapM_ putStrLn box
```

`mapM :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m [b]` is the analogue of map, but for monadic functions, its underscored cousin, `mapM_ :: Monad m => (a -> m b) -> [a] -> m ()` doesn't collect the return values and can thus be more efficient. If the return values are uninteresting, as for `putStrLn s`, `mapM_` is the better choice.

Comment: @ Daniel 
Can you please tell me if there is any way in which i can give input of Maybe Int and convert it into Int. I was working on the following code.
`code`
    
    `moves = do`
    `putStrLn " Enter the number"`
    `number <- readLn :: IO Int`
    `print number`
    `findposition number box = findIndex (==number) box :: Int`

Comment: @user If you have a reasonable default for the `Nothing` case, use `maybe :: b -> (a -> b) -> Maybe a -> b` or `Data.Maybe.fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`.